# Unable to run script through eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver

when first installed eclipse, the code ran but after script is showing error when running.

**Snippet** :

```
package demo;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\abc\\eclipse-workspace\\Demo\\driver\\exefile\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com/");
System.out.println("help");
System.out.println();
} }
```

**error** :

```
Jun 06, 2020 10:56:39 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073741819 (Exit value: -1073741819)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'
System info: host: 'SUFIYAAN', ip: '192.168.43.41', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at demo.test.main(test.java:12)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:22411/status] to be available after 20044 ms
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
    ... 10 more
```

suggest some solution.

Comment: Your selenium server will likely be down or running on a different port. Check that.

Comment: Hi you already had a same question try to update the question with this new behavior. Avoid repeating same question again and again . Welcome to sqa

Comment: how to check it. as previously it was running well. but nows it showing error. and after installing eclipse it run for first time then second time it shows error.